# How to transfer one item from one listbox to another in Visual C++ .net

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, listbox, dialog

I want to transfer one item from one listbox to another and the ability to remove it as well. I want to be able to add a item multiple times to the other listbox as well. Here is a screen shot of what I mean.

[image: Listbox example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

Button ">" event Handler:

```
 if (this->leftListBoxName->SelectedItem != nullptr)
    this->rightListBoxName->Items->Add(this->leftListBoxName->SelectedItem);
```

and the button "<" event handler:

```
if (this->rightListBoxName->SelectedItem != nullptr)
            this->rightListBoxName->Items->RemoveAt(this->rightListBoxName->SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: That's strange. Could you paste the whole code of Form1.h file to pastebin.com (or other paste* web service)?

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. I named the listboxes wrong, thank you for your help.